# How to start Janus WebRTC gateway?

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack, janus

I installed successful Janus on /usr/local/lib and I re-configure to start Janus. But when I do `sudo janus`, I get this error:

```
/*
debian@beaglebone:/usr/local/bin$ janus
---------------------------------------------------
  Starting Meetecho Janus (WebRTC Gateway) v0.1.0
---------------------------------------------------

Checking command line arguments...
Debug/log level is 4
Debug/log timestamps are disabled
Debug/log colors are enabled
Adding 'vmnet' to the ICE ignore list...
Using 10.92.200.16 as local IP...
[WARN] Token based authentication disabled
Initializing ICE stuff (Full mode, ICE-TCP candidates disabled, IPv6 support disabled)
ICE handles watchdog started
TURN REST API backend: (disabled)
[WARN] Janus is deployed on a private address (10.92.200.16) but you didn't specify any STUN server! Expect trouble if this is supposed to work over the internet and not just in a LAN...
BUNDLE is NOT going to be forced
rtcp-mux is NOT going to be forced
Fingerprint of our certificate: D2:B9:31:8F:DF:24:D8:0E:ED:D2:EF:25:9E:AF:6F:B8:34:AE:53:9C:E6:F3:8F:F2:64:15:FA:E8:7F:53:2D:38
[WARN] Data Channels support not compiled
Plugins folder: /usr/local/lib/janus/plugins
Loading plugin 'libjanus_voicemail.so'...
JANUS VoiceMail plugin initialized!
Loading plugin 'libjanus_recordplay.so'...
JANUS Record&Play plugin initialized!
Loading plugin 'libjanus_echotest.so'...
VoiceMail watchdog started
EchoTest watchdog started
Record&Play watchdog started
JANUS EchoTest plugin initialized!
Loading plugin 'libjanus_videocall.so'...
JANUS VideoCall plugin initialized!
Loading plugin 'libjanus_streaming.so'...
VideoCall watchdog started
JANUS Streaming plugin initialized!
Loading plugin 'libjanus_videoroom.so'...
JANUS VideoRoom plugin initialized!
Streaming watchdog started
Loading plugin 'libjanus_audiobridge.so'...
JANUS AudioBridge plugin initialized!
VideoRoom watchdog started
Loading plugin 'libjanus_sip.so'...
AudioBridge watchdog started
JANUS SIP plugin initialized!
Transport plugins folder: /usr/local/lib/janus/transports
Loading transport plugin 'libjanus_http.so'...
SIP watchdog started
[ERR] [janus.c:main:3684]       Couldn't load transport plugin 'libjanus_http.so': libmicrohttpd.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[FATAL] [janus.c:main:3741] No Janus API transport is available... enable at least one and restart Janus
```

*/
libjanus_http.so and libmicrohttpd.so.12 are exist on usr/local/lib/janus/transport  and /usr/local/lib

What does the error mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you missed a step or two, maybe it will fix your issue it did for me :

```
sudo apt-get install libmicrohttpd-dev libjansson-dev libnice-dev libssl-dev libsrtp-dev libsofia-sip-ua-dev libglib2.0-dev libopus-dev libogg-dev libini-config-dev libcollection-dev libwebsockets-dev pkg-config gengetopt automake libtool doxygen graphviz git cmake
```

`sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev`

`mkdir -p ~/build`

`cd ~/build`

```
git clone git://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway.git


cd janus-gateway

sh autogen.sh

./configure --disable-data-channels --disable-websockets --disable-rabbitmq --disable-docs --prefix=/opt/janus LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"

make && sudo make install
sudo make configs
```

Then :

```
cd /opt/janus/bin/ 

./janus -F /opt/janus/etc/janus/
```

Comment: Still working for me using v0.7 from 09/2019. For me it was most likely the "./configure" or the "apt install" lines that fixed it.

Comment: @RobertBain Could you please post your answer. How did you manage to install? I am new to Janus and trying to install it on AWS with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I just followed what is already written in the answer we're commenting on, nothing extra. There's a google group/forum for janus that is actively visited by Janus devs, I recommend reaching out there. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Using information found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meetecho-janus/UpDJacySurM/JXzkM7LxBgAJ) the problem was solved by running

```
make configs
```

on the installation directory.